# Using UFW, if I create a rule, will it apply to both IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: iptables, ufw, ipv6, ipv4

Will UFW create the appropriate rules in both iptables and ip6tables?

Comment: Which rule? Are you talking about allowing/denying a port? An address range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends whether the rule you create is generic, such as

```
ufw allow 22/tcp
```

or is specific to one address family, such as

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22 proto tcp
```

---

Ex.:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22 proto tcp
Rule added
$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
```

but

```
$ sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
Rule added
Rule added (v6)

$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Is it safe to remove the `22/tcp (v6)` – `Anywhere` rule along with the `22/tcp` – `Anywhere` rule in order to lock down ssh access via port 22 to only one IP address? Or do I lock myself out, that way? Asking because as you show (and as it worked for me too), the command to allow only a specific IP only adds the `22/tcp` – `<IP address>`, not a `22/tcp (v6)` – `<IP address>` rule.